# How to set canonical tags using Yoast

Tags: wordpress, canonical-url, rel-canonical, yoast

I am stuck on fixing canonical issue. I found Yoast's .htaccess file, but not understanding what to put in there.

How do I code it into my website?

Comment: .htaccess should have nothing to do with it.   Canonical tags are usually set in the `<head>` of HTML documents.

Comment: Can you tell me the complete procedure how to do that?

Comment: Fahad's answer looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix it differently, apparently the thing you're asking is not controlled by Yoast but by Wordpress itself. Follow these steps;

1. Open wordpress dashboard.
2. Goto settings.
3. Goto General.
4. Edit your URL in Wordpress and Site Address bars.